# How to make Choose an Option the default on drop down for configurable products?

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1

When I make a configurable product, I would like the default selection on the drop-down to be "Choose an Option..." (as apparently it should be).

For example, for a product I have:

Choose an Option...
Yes, add accessory +$9.99
No, do not add accessory

When I view the product on the frontend, the default selection is "Yes, add accessory +$9.99" instead of "Choose an Option..." like it should be and thus makes the default price $9.99 higher than it should be.

How do I fix this? I suppose I could make simple products and just add these options as Custom Options, but it will not track inventory if I do it that way.

Comment: you need to select the default option as "Choose an Option"?

Comment: There is no option for that. By default, magento is supposed to make that the default option but it's not

Answer (score 1):

I think you have once set one of the `associate product` to default. Since that section is `radio button` you cannot undo this.

But you can get way around to it. You simply need to perform following task step by step:

**Simply uncheck that selected product in `Associate product` list and check again & hit save.**

If this doesn't help follow following steps:

1. Uncheck that product (chosen to be default) from **associate product** list and save that **config-product** (please take note of this product's id, you will need later)
2. Now, go to **Associate Product** section and search & choose that product (the one you unchecked in step-1)
3. This time do not choose any item to be `Default` and simply save the **config-product**.

Hope this will do what you intend to.

**Update**

To remove any extension you can do two way:

1. Go to Magento Connect Manager and `uninstall` it from there (if you have installed the extension through this)
2. Or just go to `app/etc/modules/Easylife_Switcher.xml` and set `<active>` to false **OR** even delete this file along with `app/code/community/Easylife/Switcher` folders and it's belonging files in design folder.

**I believe this extension has update some other as well, so if removing this doesn't work then you should reinstall fresh magento.**

Comment: None of the associate products are set as default. Magento is picking the first associate product (based on ID) and making it default on the frontend

Comment: Do you have any jquery/javascript for this? Or else, I doubt you have customized core files: `php/phtml`.

Comment: No I have not changed any of the core files of magento

Comment: Can you add your screenshot of `associated product section`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8NsBrHh

Comment: And your sites url?

Comment: Here is the specific link that the screenshot shows: http://www.jdmotorsportsoffroad.com/audio/arctic-cat/prowler/complete-2-speaker-system.html

Comment: Can you replace following file - `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` from fresh magento and see if that helps. I strongly doubt there is changes on this file or javascript is added for this job.

Comment: Okay, I have done that but it did not seem to fix the problem

Comment: Any other advice?

Comment: Could you backup and replace `js/varien/configurable.js` AND `js/prototype/prototype.js` files. That might help.

Comment: That didn't work either. Do I need to reinstall Magento to fix it at this point?

Comment: I am pretty sure, you have js or jquery somewhere which manipulating this. However, yes you can reinstall. But again, if it is caused by some extension you have, and you install them in fresh magento you will have this problem.

Comment: I am using only one extension called EasyLife Switcher (https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) and when I disabled it, it seems to have fixed the issue. I realized I really don't need this with the 1.9.1 swatches so I'm going to try and delete it. I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of Magento so is there an easy way to remove extensions? Will it bring any edited files back to fresh installs or do I need to manually do that?

Comment: Check my updated answer.